# Getting two servlets to use the same object using Servlet context

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to write a simple program where i can put a HashMap on an application scoped session and get two applications/contexts deployed as two war files access the HashMap.

Servlet 1

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HashMap<String ,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("1", "1");

        this.getServletContext().setAttribute("usermanager", hm);
        this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().setAttribute("usermanager2", hm);   
    }
```

Servlet 2

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{

    HashMap newMap2 = (HashMap) this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("usermanager"); 
    HashMap newMap3 = (HashMap) this.getServletContext().getAttribute("usermanager2"); 

    System.out.println("newmap2 size " + newMap2.size());
    System.out.println("newmap3 size " + newMap3.size());   
}
```

To test this i restarted Tomcat 6 then run access Servlet 1 first so that it initializes the Hashmap object. When i subsequently access Servlet 2 i get a NULL-POINTER error which is pointing at the line number where i tried to call newMap2.size()

What am i doing wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Peter Cetinski already mentioned a Servlet Context always relates to exactly one web application (WAR file). Nevertheless, the Servlet API provides a way to access 'foreign' Servlet Contexts by calling [`javax.servlet.ServletContext.getContext(uriPath)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29).

So if you really want/need to spread your Servlets across different WARs and communication between them is required, you can do this.

Assuming that **Servlet 1** is located in web application **warA**, **Servlet 2** located in web application **warB**, and the applications context path is the same as the web application name (e.g. `http://myserver/warA` and `http://myserver/warB`), the code for Servlet 2 could look like this:

```
/* retrieve foreign context */
ServletContext ctxWarA = this.getServletContext().getContext("warA");

/* ... and work with it */
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) ctxWarA.getAttribute("usermanager");
```

---

There are some constraints:

- you must explicitly allow `warB` to access the foreign context by specifying this in the applications' `context.xml`: `<Context crossContext="true"/>`
- this setup is proprietary (I cannot tell you how this works in other application servers/servlet engines)
- if you want to share custom classes they must be shared between the applications (place them in `<tomcat>/lib`
- in the standard setup you work with different classloaders for `warA` and `warB`, you should be aware of that
- Tomcat does not guarantee a certain startup sequence (there is no way to configure this). In your case `warB` must be able to handle this and expect `warA` to be not yet started

If you need to share objects/information between web applications, I'd consider those alternative approaches:

- a shared singleton located in Tomcat/lib (I know a singleton, but it works)
- an object located in the JNDI tree ([Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html))
- information required to build the cache in a shared data store (file, database, etc.) and each applications loads the data at startup

Comment: How is the object initialised when located in the JNDI tree.

Comment: @ziggy: added a link to the Tomcat documentation for JNDI management. Explains it very well (just give it a try)... it seems to me that you're behind *Generic JavaBean Resources*.

Comment: I have seen that section before. I was a bit worried as it refered to JavaBeans but my object is not a pure javabean. It also mentioned that  new instance of the class is created everytime a lookup is performed on the object. This worried me as i need just one instance throughout the application.

Comment: Just read the documentation again, it somehow seems to be buggy. It all depends on how you implement the resource factory.. section 'Adding Custom Resource Factories'

Comment: The examples you showed with ServletContext works quite well. I might stick to that for now and keep it simple. The JNDI documentation seem to be lacking sufficient documentation/examples for how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

ServletContext is shareable only within a web application.  If you are deploying in 2 different WARs then you have 2 web applications.